# String manipulation with gcc 4.8.1 and Mingw gcc 4.7.2

Tags: c, mingw

why does the following code "work" on MinGW GCC 4.7.2, and is not working (as opposed to) on GCC?

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main() {
   char *str; 
   gets(str);
   return 0;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.
Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above has undefined behavior: you didn't initialize `str` and you're passing its indeterminate value into `gets`. So `gets` likely ends up scribbling to some random place in memory.

This is why your code *works* (for some definition of work) in MinGW-gcc 4.7.2 but not the other -- because undefined behavior means anything can happen, including what you're seeing.